# How to set a "default folder" to an Asset Picker

Tags: asseturlselector

I'm trying to create an asset picker which matches my needs. I have the asset picker in my Custom Field and i want it to open the dialog from the List he is in.

I wrote down this code:

```
urlSelector = new AssetUrlSelector();
urlSelector.PickerButtonText = "Add";
urlSelector.AllowExternalUrls = true;

//Get current list
string app = this.Context.Request.Url.ToString();
Match m = Regex.Match(app, @"/Lists/.*/");


urlSelector.DisplayLookInSection = false;

//Associate the right path
urlSelector.DefaultOpenLocationUrl = "~Site" + m.Value;
urlSelector.DefaultToLastUsedLocation = false;
urlSelector.AutoPostBack = true;
this.Controls.Add(urlSelector);
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you ever found a solution?

Comment: Sadly not, as I can remember, I change my mind about how the control must be.